# argparse concatenate cli options

Tags: python, argparse

Just starting to learn python and playing around with passing command line options to a python script. I'm trying to concatenate two or more arguments and pass it on to a string variable,

e.g.,

```
myscript.py http://www.domain.com 1234
```

put it in to a string variable called `url`, which then should have the value of "http://www.domain.com:1234"

I'm not quite sure on how to archive that. It's quite straight forward to do it with `raw_input` and some string manipulation, but I wonder if this can be done with `argparse` as well.

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like argparse isn't all that useful in this case.

Answer (score 7):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('server') # first positional argument
parser.add_argument('port') # second positional argument
args = parser.parse_args()

url = '%s:%s' % (args.server, args.port)
print url
```

Answer (score 2):

argparse is one way to solve it, but may be overkill if you're just learning (YMMV).

If you import the `sys` module, the command line arguments passed to you are available in a list of strings at `sys.argv`

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print "Not enough args!"
    sys.exit(0)
# sys.argv[0] is the name of your script, the rest are parameters
url = "%s:%s" % (sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
print url
```

Comment: Funny how the argparse example is in fact nearly as short ;)

Comment: @delnan -- yeah, that does kind of undercut my "why bother with argparse?" argument...

Comment: argparse seems to be quite powerful though, but looking at the examples on http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html was a bit overwhelming, especially if you just start out with the language.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do,

```
argstring = ':'.join(args[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a variable with the string http://www.domain.com:1234 from command line input then do the following:

```
if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
    result = '%s:%s' % tuple(sys.argv[1:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Amber,

that was exactly what I was looking for

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from urllib import urlopen
import argparse

usage='will be using it later'

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, description=usage, add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('link')
parser.add_argument('port')
args = parser.parse_args()

url = '%s:%s' % (args.link, args.port)
link = urlopen(url)
content=link.read()

print(content)
```

just a bit confused with this line "url = '%s:%s' % (args.link, args.port)"
does that line take the arguments in brackets and add it to the string variable 'url'?

Jack

Answer (score 0):

> just a bit confused with this line
>   "url = '%s:%s' % (args.link,
>   args.port)" does that line take the
>   arguments in brackets and add it to
>   the string variable 'url'?

That format is actually not recommended any more. ( see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html). The simplest way to do the same with a currently recommended method would be:-

```
url = '{0}:{1}'.format( args.link , args.port )
```

where {n} is the nth variable within format( variables ). This method will always convert the arguments to a string for you.

The older method using %s does the same; the 's' meaning turn an argument into a string, but there has to be exactly as many '%s' flags within the string as there are arguments after the % sign after the string. Don't worry about this, but if you're learning, use .format().